# how to loop infinitely inside a Text widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Well it is pretty simple, just increment the counter infinitely and show it with the widget Text()
simple, right?..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: RainbowButton()));
}

class _RainbowButtonState extends State<RainbowButton> {
  int counter = 0;
  void _increase() {
    super.initState();
    while (true) {
      setState(() {
        counter++;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child:
          Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
        Text(counter.toString()),
      ]),
    )));
  }
}

class RainbowButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const RainbowButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RainbowButtonState createState() => _RainbowButtonState();
}
```

it only displays a 0 but it doesn't go up.

this is all i got so far, my respects and thanks for your time. i feel a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: Goodday... just to clarify do you want it to a loop without user interaction? based on your code it looks like the theres a problem in your implementation on initState.. Here's a reference: https://medium.com/filledstacks/how-to-call-a-function-on-start-in-flutter-stateless-widgets-28d90ab3bf49

Comment: hey, thank you, yes without user input, still i don't know what i'm missing, can you help me to wrap my mind around this, i think i bumped into the same article, but thank you really.

Comment: Your loop is *blocking*; it increments `counter` in an infinite loop but never yields to allow the event loop to run, to redraw the screen, accept user input, etc.  Once your code enters that infinite loop, *no other code can execute*.  If you want to increment `counter`, say, every second, then use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stateful pages is shown, you can set action/s on the `initState()` function. And as for your specific application you can follow jamesdlin advice by using `Timer.periodic`.

Example Code:

```
void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        counter++;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: now that's smart. thanks, jamesdin, thanks Kei Credo!.